# "Install-Package : Exception calling CloneRequest" while installing Powershell modules over SSH

Tags: powershell, cygwin

I am trying to automate installing a module from a custom repository on a windows machine by pushing a ps1 script from a Linux machine to the windows machine, and then trying to execute the script over ssh. The windows is running a cygwin server. When I run the ps1 script directly on powershell, the script runs fine. But when I run the same over ssh, it fails with the following error:

```
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Exception calling "CloneRequest" with "3" argument(s): "Object reference not set
to an instance of an object."
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1875 char:34
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

The script fails at the line:

```
Find-Module -Name <module name> -AllVersions -Repository <repo name> | Install-Module -SkipPublisherCheck -Scope AllUsers -Force
```

This is how I am calling the script from the linux machine:

```
ssh user@windowsIp powershell -NonInteractive  -File E:\moduleInstaller.ps1 repositoryUrl moduleName moduleVersion
```